# Disable Post/Page comment emails for creators

Tags: posts, comments

I have a Wordpress based blog with several admin users, and many pages with comments. There is a main email account set up for all comments to be emailed to.

We have noticed that besides the main email account getting notified about a comment, the person whose account created the particular article or page is also getting the exact same email as the main account gets. Is there a way (or a plugin) to disable this functionality, and only have comments go to the mail email instead of the administrators (who all have access to this main email account)?

I would prefer to keep emails on for all users for certain posts if possible.

Can anyone help me with this?